# Div Flickering onmouseover, onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have image and I want a div over it when mouse over but I don't want it onmouseout. I wrote the code and it works but it's flickering. 
here is the code:

```
<div id="div" style="opacity:0.6; background-color:#2c3e50; width:136px; height:163px; z-index:199; position:absolute; vertical-align:top; font-size:120px; text-align:center; color:White; display:none;">1</div>
<img alt="ברק לוי" src="" style="background-color:red; height:163px; width:136px" onmouseover="picture(true)" onmouseout="picture(false)"/>
```

---

```
function picture(bool) {
    if (bool) {
        document.getElementById("div").style.display = "block";
    }
    else if (bool==false) {
        document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tacekami/4/edit)
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to use `onmouseout` event on `div`

```
<div id="div" style="opacity:0.6; background-color:#2c3e50; width:136px; height:163px; z-index:199; position:absolute; vertical-align:top; font-size:120px; text-align:center; color:White; display:none;" onmouseout="picture(false)">1</div>

<img alt="ברק לוי" src="" style="background-color:red; height:163px; width:136px" onmouseover="picture(true)"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the  `onmouseover="picture(true)" onmouseout="picture(false)` to your div div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div" style="opacity:0.6; background-color:#2c3e50; width:136px; height:163px; z-index:199; position:absolute; vertical-align:top; font-size:120px; text-align:center; color:White; display:block;" onmouseover="picture(true)" onmouseout="picture(false)">1
<img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/vbKNWRZ.gif" id="image"/></div>
</body>
</html>


function picture(bool) {
    if (bool) {
        document.getElementById("div").style.opacity = "0.6";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("div").style.opacity = "0.0";
    }
}
```

Try this. The flickering is due to the fact that when you set "Display: none" it isn't there, and the "mouseout" is triggered. While setting opacity to 0.0, it's still there as invisible, but the mouseout will not trigger.